# Create variables with incremented names and store values in them, all with a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, increment

In order to simplify my work under R I would like to replace the following code :

```
testQ1 <- results(dds, name="XXXX", alpha=0.05, 
                 filterFun=ihw, 
                 lfcThreshold=1)

testQ2 <- results(dds, name="YYYY", alpha=0.05, 
                 filterFun=ihw, 
                 lfcThreshold=1)

testQ3 <- results(dds, name="ZZZZ",
                 alpha=0.05,
                 filterFun=ihw,
                 lfcThreshold=1)
```

With a loop :

```
treeQ <- c('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ')

outQ<-0

for( i in 1:length(treeQ)){  
  outQ[i]<-results(dds, name=treeQ[i], alpha=0.05, filterFun=ihw, lfcThreshold=1)
  }
```

But I get :

```
Error in outQ[i] <- results(dds, name = treeQ[i], alpha = 0.05, filterFun = ihw,  : 
      incompatible types (from S4 to double) in subassignment type fix
```

I can not solve this problem. 
I have also heard that "apply" would be a better solution than a "for" loop but in this case I am stuck with incremented var names...

Comment: There's no reason you need to be stuck with incremented variable names. This would be much easier to work with in R if you just used a list (with or without names). Then you could just `lapply` over your inputs to get the results you want.

Comment: I believe you need to initialize outQ like

outQ <- c(), 
or if the return is  more complicated
outQ <- list()

Answer (score 0):

Using lists should solve this.

```
outQ<- {}
    for( i in 1:length(treeQ)){  
      outQ[[i]]<-results(dds, name=treeQ[i], alpha=0.05, filterFun=ihw, lfcThreshold=1)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to comments and answer, declaring empty list `outQ <- list()` and using the double bracket `[[ ]]` index solved my problem.

*(For now, I am not comfortable with lists and the R lapply function, because I did a lot of php coding so the "for loop" speaks more to me, but I will try some lapply.)*

Below is the complete working code that creates variables with incremented names, makes calculations, filters and orders data, stores the results in the variables and exports the data in CSV files, all in the same loop. Using such loop is very helpful.

If it could help someone.
Thank a lot for your help.

```
  treeQ <- c('XXXX', 'YYYY', 'ZZZZ')

    outQ <- list()
    res05 <- list()
    resOrdered <- list()

    for( i in 1:length(treeQ)){  
      outQ[[i]]<-results(dds, name=treeQ[i], alpha=0.05, filterFun=ihw, lfcThreshold=1)
      res05[[i]] <- subset(outQ[[i]], padj < 0.05)
      print(nrow(res05[[i]]))
      resOrdered[[i]] <- res05[[i]][order(res05[[i]]$log2FoldChange),]
      resOrdered[[i]] <- as.data.frame(resOrdered[[i]])
      write.csv(resOrdered[[i]], file = paste("20191009_out_", treeQ[i], ".csv", sep=""))
      print(paste(i," : ok !",sep=" "))
      }
```